# Restricted standard deviation of survival time

Tags: mathematical-statistics, survival, conditional-expectation

I'm working through a paper on restricted mean survival time and I cannot figure out how this paper jumps from one step to the next.

The restricted mean survival time $\mu$ is the mean survival time of $X = \min(T, t^*)$ where T is a random variable (time-to-event) and $t^{*}$ is a specified time horizon. Then,

$ \mu = E(X) = E[min(T, t^*)] = \int_{0}^{t^*} S(t) dt $

where $S(t) = Pr(T > t)$ is the survival function. To find the variance of $\mu$,

$E(X^2) = E(T^2|T \leq t^{*}) Pr(T \leq t^{*}) + {t^{*}}^2 Pr(T > t^{*})$

Then, since $Pr(T \leq t^{*}) = 1 - S(t^{*})$,

$E(T^2|T \leq t^{*}) Pr(T \leq t^{*}) = \int_{0}^{t^*} t^2 f(t) dt$

I am able to follow up to this part, but they then go on to state,

$E(T^2|T \leq t^{*}) Pr(T \leq t^{*}) = {t^{*}}^2 [1 - S(t^{*})] - \int_{0}^{t^*} 2t[1-S(t)] dt$

I'm not sure where they got this relationship from, would anyone be able to provide some intuition / a point in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They used [integration by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts#:%7E:text=In%20calculus%2C%20and%20more%20generally,of%20their%20derivative%20and%20antiderivative.).

If $h$ and $g$ are functions then since $(hg)' = h'g + hg'$,
$$
\int h'g = [hg] - \int hg'
$$

Here in the integral
$$
\int_{0}^{t^*} t^2 f(t) dt
$$
they used $h'(t)=f(t)$ (thus $h(t) = F(t)$) and $g(t)=t^2$ (and $g'(t) = 2t$) which gives,
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{t^*} t^2 f(t) dt &= \left[t^2 F(t) \right]_0^{t^*} - \int_0^{t^*}2tF(t)dt \\
&=  \left[t^2 \left (1-S(t) \right ) \right]_0^{t^*} - \int_0^{t^*}2t\left(1-S(t) \right)dt
\end{align*}
Since $S(0) = 1$,

$$
\int_{0}^{t^*} t^2 f(t) dt = t^{*2}\left(1-S(t^*) \right) - \int_0^{t^*}2t\left(1-S(t) \right)dt
$$

Comment: Ah, time to brush up on my calculus. Thank you!